# Run a jar automatically

Tags: java

I am running automatic tests and after each test, all the sessions of these tests are automatically inserted into a temporary table.
My tool (in JAR), checks this temporary table and when it finds a new session inserted, my tool scans it and then delete this entry from the temporary table.

Actually I can do that manually without any problem (telling my tool to check the temporary table, if there is something new, scan it…), but I want to do that automatically, I mean my tool always running, and checks automatically (for example every hour) if there is something new in the temporary table.

Could you help me how I can do that ? I guess I need a server where I execute my tool 24/24, which type of server?  Thank you very much

Comment: Quartz is a very good library for executing scheduled tasks. Alternatively, if you're on a Linux system, you can set up a cron job?

Comment: The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler. U need to create a Cron.

Comment: if you are on windows [this](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjVqvr94cPHAhXFfhoKHcNvDGY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F15783553%2Frun-a-jar-file-using-windows-scheduler&ei=jSDcVZWwPMX9acPfsbAG&usg=AFQjCNFdM6lu99sOixTMbaV7ynaZSbND6Q&cad=rja) could also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a unix based system, you could run the jar as a cronjob. The following would run a jar every 30 seconds.

```
*/30 * * * * java -jar /path/to/jar/myjar.jar
```

Read the following to learn how to setup a cronjob correctly https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

For windows, use task scheduler. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26932169/802061 as suggested by @kevin-esche in the comments

Comment: OP hasn't specified if they are on a Unix based system. If they are Windows, this is not an option.

Comment: Correct. Although OP has asked which type of server he should run this on.

Answer (score 0):

Which database you are using.
If SQL, you can create the jobs in the database server itself.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server yes! could you give more details ?

Comment: You can create the Jobs. and schedule for every 10 mins. from the job you can execute the jar.

Comment: https://sushantp.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/running-an-exe-or-program-as-sql-server-job/