# Scheduled Task won't work properly for any scheduled task involving a JAR file

Tags: batch-file, jar, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2000

Is there any fix to this? So far I've resorted to using a software called "System Scheduler", but I really want to know if I can manage to make it work with Windows' built in Scheduled Task.

.bat:

```
start /D C:\Jars\Load\ /B LoadInc.jar
```

I also tried:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin\java.exe" -jar 
"C:\Jars\Load\LoadInc.jar"
```

As for the Task Scheduler, its only function is running the .bat at a specific time. I've tried it of course using "Run now".

I noticed it opens the "javaw" process for like 5 seconds (Meaning it does nothing). But if I go and double click the .bat, it works with no issues and takes like 5 minutes to do the process (Of course, with the process "javaw" open 'til the end").

Comment: Please either [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46692350/edit) to provide the information which you have entered into the task scheduler and also the content of the batch file, or find a site where the membership are mind readers!

Comment: Hah, my bad. Edited it with more info, @Compo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a jar file using windows scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783553/run-a-jar-file-using-windows-scheduler)